# What is the purpose of Solution.Title/Description?

Tags: solution-package

You can set "Title" and "Description" on SharePoint Solutions:

```
<Solution xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"
  SolutionId="[GUID]"
  Title="*** Where is this displayed? ***"
  Description="*** Where is this displayed? ***"
  ResetWebServerModeOnUpgrade="Recycle"
  SharePointProductVersion="15.0">
```

But once set I can't see anywhere where it is used or how it can be accessed. So is there any point to set Title + Description for SharePoint Solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Description: Optional string. Specifies a description for the solution.

Title: Optional string. Specifies the title of the solution.

Comment: Yes, that's doesn't say much does it. Once I've set Description for a solution and have deployed it as a WSP where can I view the description?

Comment: Did you check on the central administration?

Comment: Yep, I can't see that "Description" is displayed anywhere in the farm solutions area. Have you found it?

Answer (score 1):

Solution title is actually the name of solution, that you use while **Deploying** solution throw central administration, STSADM or using powershell.

Solution description is just metadata about the particular solution, as if solution name isn't providing enough information about your solution, you can just add few lines of description instead of having long names.

You can't just create a solution and deploy it, you need to maintain records for future references,

for example if a developer develops a solution for company and after a while he leaves then new developer needs to know what solution is actually doing instead of going throw code.

Comment: Actually, "Name" is the name of the solution which ends up as the WSP-package name and which you use to reference the solution in CA or via PS. Title is something else, you can set it but I can't find a way to view it if you have a WSP, it's not displayed in CA and there is no "Title" or "Description"-property in PS for Get-SPSolution.

Comment: Never said there is any property for description in PS or CA !! change your wsp file extension to  .zip and you will be able to find whats in it

Comment: No, I know, didn't say you did. My point is, that as far as I can see, there is no way to access the "Title" and "Description" for a solution using the standard tooling (Central Admin / PowerShell). It's only visible in the package.package and manifest.xml.

Comment: I think you are getting confused with Title and Name, they are same thing ;), check this link out, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms412929.aspx, however description is for developer's reference and Name for developer and IT pros :)

Comment: Yeah, "Name" is only for the Package Manager, whatever you put there ends up being the filename for the WSP-file. "Title" and "Description" are optional. If you set Package Manager\Name = "MySolution" you get a WSP named MySolution.wsp. If you set Title = "HowToReference" solution stays the same. So, is there a way to reference a solution via it's Title?

Comment: Please refrain from excessive use of comments. If you want to discuss further details about the answer or question, please do so in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/411/sharepoint)!

Answer (score 0):

what you put is all optional! ;) you dont have to put any if you really want but it isnt recommended!

It is accessible through central admin under opperations within solution managment!

When you look into the wsp within detail its nice to know what that wsp does and its name! it can be used as an example when you want to use a utility tool to find a wsp by its title ratha than a guid (title is friendly and easy to remember!)

To get it you would need to use SPFarm programmacitally!
a good example is an app that i made http://deployretractallwsp.codeplex.com/ it gets those wsp's but not using the title ;) but you can very very easily! I didnt do title beacause it can be blank ;)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms412929.aspx

Comment: Yes, you can manually view "Title" and "Description" by looking at the manifest.xml in a WSP-file. But these two properties are not exposed via the Server Object Model and not displayed in Central Admin which is the point of my question. You can set "Title" to "X" and "Name" to "Y" which will generate a WSP named y.wsp.

Answer (score 0):

The Title & Description properties for the Solution element can be seen in the Solution Gallery if you add those columns to the default view.  That is where I have benefited from them.